# Using _getch to create a linked list and reversing the list

Tags: c++, linked-list

Currently, I am able to type 9 characters in my linked list and then print them. Right after I do that, it should give me the reverse order of the list I typed, but its only giving me the last letter of the list and then it exits. I know my reverse function at the bottom is incorrect, but I am not sure how to approach it. Any help would be appreciated.

````
class Node
{
public:
    char c;
    Node *next;
    Node *curr;
    Node(char cc) { c = cc; next = nullptr; };
};


void main()
{
    char c;
    Node *start = nullptr;
    Node *end = nullptr;

    int i = 0;
    cout << "Original Linked List:" << endl;
    while (i++ <= 10)
    {
        c = _getch();
        Node *p = new Node(c);
        if (start == nullptr)
        {
            start = p;
            end = start;
        }
        else
        {
            end->next = p;
            end = p;
        }
        cout << c;

    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Reversed Linked List:" << endl;

    while (start != nullptr) {
        Node *curr = new Node(c);
        start = curr->next;
        curr->next = end;
        end = curr;
        curr = start;

    }

    cout << c << endl;
    system("pause");
}```
````

Comment: Why don't you use `std::vector`?  Also, it is `int main` not `void main`.

Comment: You don't actually have a reverse function in the sample you gave. I recommend Googling c++ function, and reading through some of the tutorials to understand what a function is.

Comment: `_getch` gets a character. It does nothing whatsoever to reverse a linked list. Please supply a better tittle. I'd do it myself, but there are too many questions that already have similar names to Reverse a Linked List. Might be something worth researching in that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well what you want to do,
here is some basic solution for demo, following your style.
Please, note changes I've made, regarding Node struct, iterating, etc.
Also to mention, that allocated nodes need to be freed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
struct Node {
    char c;
    Node* next;
    Node* prev;
    Node(char cc):c(cc),next(nullptr),prev(nullptr) { };
};
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char c;
    Node* start = nullptr;
    Node* end = nullptr;

    int i = 0;
    cout << "Original Linked List:" << endl;
    while (++i <= 10)
    {
        c = _getch();
        Node* p = new Node(c);
        if (start == nullptr)
        {
            start = p;
            end = start;
            p->next = end;
            p->prev = start;
        }
        else
        {
            p->prev = end;
            end = p;
            p->next = end;
        }
        cout << c;

    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Reversed Linked List:" << endl;
    Node* curr = end;
    while (start != curr) {

        cout << curr->c;
        start = curr->next;
        curr = curr->prev;

    }
    cout << "\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The output is

Original Linked List:

1234567890

Reversed Linked List:

0987654321

Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is actually close to what I was asking for. 

The only thing is that the user should be allowed to only type to a certain amount of characters and the program should automatically run the reverse function instead of the user hitting enter. So once the user types in "1234567890", once "0" is entered, the program should automatically output the reverse linked list. 

I hope that clarifies things.

Comment: Recommend highlighting the changes you made and explaining them, otherwise you have provided a code-only answer and code only answers generally result in more questions form the asker or blind acceptance and the asker getting little more from the answer than  a chance at leveling up their copy and paste skills.

Comment: @Boki That's basically what I was looking for, thank you so much for your help. It definitely made things more clear for me to understand.